# Create Big forms Android best practices

Tags: android

I want to create big forms in an Android applications, with a lot of questions and inputs, what is the best way to do that ? Did I need to user Scroll View, List View ? If it's a List View what kind of adapter is the best ?

Comment: For scroll view vs list view it depends-  how well does your form break down into repeatable parts that can be used as rows?  List view is more efficient if it can br broken down, but you'll have to be careful about saving data around row recycling.  ScrollView is simpler but uses more memory.  As for an adapter-  I can't imagine a scenario where you won't have to write a custom one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Generally, it is not a good idea to present a huge form on a single page on a mobile device. Users don't like to scroll pages after pages of views to fill forms. It can be disorienting and hard to navigate. On smaller devices, things will be even worse.
- Consider breaking a big form down by functional areas and present a smaller UI instead. This will make it easier for the user. You could organize your form in a view pager where you can have several pages.
- My experience with ListView (this may apply to RecyclerView too) is that adding an edit field to a row has some challenges in terms of handling focus, touch events etc. The listView does not handle it very smoothly. So it is possible to use these but it can be tricky. Unless there are lots of similar rows, listView does not give you much. Doing a ScrollView or a TableLayout will be fine.